# Not For Replication not working SQL

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I set table column properties [image: Column properties]. according to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237102(v=sql.80).aspx).

After activating the NOT FOR REPLICATION option, connections from replication agents to Publisher A insert rows with values such as 1, 2, 3, 4. These are replicated to Publisher B without being changed (that is, 1, 2, 3, 4). Connections from replication agents at Publisher B get values 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004. Those are replicated to A without being changed. When all data is distributed or merged, both Publishers have values 1, 2, 3, 4, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004. The next locally inserted value at Publisher A is 5. The next locally inserted value at Publisher B is 1005.

But when i tried above procedure and tried insert query, last row id value was 10 and then tried insert query.

```
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BusOprtn].[dbo].[WinFormMaster] ON
insert into [BusOprtn].[dbo].[WinFormMaster] (Id,Name)  values(40,'fdsf');
```

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BusOprtn].[dbo].[WinFormMaster] OFF`. After this when i insert new row in edit mode of sql management studio, it inserts new row with 41 id but is should be 11. what can be the mistake.

If there is no mistake above then how can i solve my motive of replication or syncronization with identity column as primary key. If it is not possible by synchronization, i want to go with merge replication.

Comment: if you can change the schema, consider adding a publisherID to distinguish between publishers instead of using the same column with mutually exclusive (in this case, +1000) values.

Answer (score 1):

No mistake, after running an insert, the identity value will be 1 + the last inserted value. You will need to do a dbcc checkident(TableName, newvalue, Reseed)

Comment: What is the table name? if it is authors do this

Comment: What is the table name? if it is authors do this  - DBCC CheckIdent(Authors), note the current identity value and the current row value. By setting it to 0 what you are doing is setting the value that will be handed out by user (non replication) processes on your subscriber. You need to ensure that this identity value is not currently in use. The current column value is the highest value in use in that table which could be the value assigned by a user process or a replication process. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the next identity value locally to be 4, after the following merged: 1 2 3 1001 1002 1003.  However, the identity value is 7, which means that the identity was incremented event though NOT FOR REPLICATION on the identity column should prevent incrementing.

In this case, you do not want to reseed or turn modify INSERT IDENTITY on tables.

You do need to specify the type of replication.  For example,

**If you are using transactional replication with the immediate-updating Subscribers option, 
do not use the IDENTITY NOT FOR REPLICATION design. Instead, create the IDENTITY property at the
Publisher only, and have the Subscriber use just the base data type (for example, int). Then, the next identity value is always generated at the Publisher**

[Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237102(v=sql.80).aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[BusOprtn].[dbo].[WinFormMaster].[id]', RESEED, 0);
GO
```

Comment: This may be an answer to the question, but you need to provide *how* this is a fix to the OP's issue, not just the code to fix it.

Comment: Please provide a little explanation. Code-only answers are (sometimes) good enough, but code+explanation answers are (almost always) better

Comment: what should i do in merge replication case because insertion is done at subscriber end also in offline case.